# Azure AADDS multi region

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, replication

Need some pointers on how one could achieve "true" multi region setup for AADDS.
As per Microsoft's documentation, AADDS is "designed" to be "single regioned". Although it provides some (arguably) redundancy by spinning up essentially 2 managed domain controllers, it does not take into account performance.
Microsoft recommends (and there isn't really any other way to do this) setting up VPN's or VNET peering in order to access your AADDS from other regions, but this has huge impact over performance, and also over actual redundancy (HA designs should be multi region imo, and AADDS should be HA).

We're deploying Windows VM's in (at the time of writing this question) 10 regions, with AADDS in West Europe. We're seeing huge penalties for our apps that require/rely on LDAP ( >10s in some regions) for even the most basic LDAP queries with quite the small return payload.

Was hoping someone figured out a way to mirror/cache AADDS in a new region, like maybe adding a new worker DC or some black magic, so that VMs and services would connect more locally?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AADDS Multi-Region Support is already a [requested feature](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/30981619-span-aadds-domain-across-multi-regions#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D) and is under works currently. However, there is no ETA to share at the moment. You can follow [What's new in Azure Active Directory?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/whats-new) for updates.

The only option to achieve Geo-redundancy is by deploying ADDS across multiple regions via IaaS VMs, Vnet pairing, and VPN gateways.

Also, for [high availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/faqs#does-azure-ad-domain-services-include-high-availability-options), each Azure AD Domain Services managed domain includes two domain controllers. You don't manage or connect to these domain controllers, they're part of the managed service. If you deploy Azure AD Domain Services into a region that supports Availability Zones, the domain controllers are distributed across zones. In regions that don't support Availability Zones, the domain controllers are distributed across Availability Sets. You have no configuration options or management control over this distribution.

Comment: Hello Stefan, I hope the above answer helps you. If yes, please accept the answer so that it can help others well. If you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to Azure [AADDS FAQ documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/faqs), they do support a fail-over to another geo location.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-create-replica-set) page in order to create a replica set for your AADDS deployment.